# trying to specify the file path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to specify my file path in the script that I got from here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Outputs-directory-size-964d07ff

The current file path points to the directory, but I am unable to locate the variable that I need to change in order to specify a different path.

```
  # Get-DirStats.ps1
  # Written by Bill Stewart (bstewart@iname.com)
  # Outputs file system directory statistics.

   #requires -version 2

 <#
 .SYNOPSIS
 Outputs file system directory statistics.

 .DESCRIPTION
 Outputs file system directory statistics (number of files and the sum of           all file sizes) for one or more directories.

 .PARAMETER Path
 Specifies a path to one or more file system directories. Wildcards are not      permitted. The default path is the current directory (.).

 .PARAMETER LiteralPath
 Specifies a path to one or more file system directories. Unlike Path, the value of LiteralPath is used exactly as it is typed.

 .PARAMETER Only
 Outputs statistics for a directory but not any of its subdirectories.

 .PARAMETER Every
 Outputs statistics for every directory in the specified path instead of only the first level of directories.

 .PARAMETER FormatNumbers
 Formats numbers in the output object to include thousands separators.

 .PARAMETER Total
 Outputs a summary object after all other output that sums all statistics.
 #>

 [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Path")]
 param( 

 [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Path",ValueFromPipeline =$true)]  

  $Path=(get-location).Path,
  [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="LiteralPath")]
  [String[]] $LiteralPath,
  [Switch] $Only,
  [Switch] $Every,
  [Switch] $FormatNumbers,
  [Switch] $Total
)

begin {
  $ParamSetName = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
  if ( $ParamSetName -eq "Path" ) {
  $PipelineInput = ( -not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Path") ) -and ( -
  not $Path )
  }
 elseif ( $ParamSetName -eq "LiteralPath" ) {
 $PipelineInput = $false
}

# Script-level variables used with -Total.
[UInt64] $script:totalcount = 0
[UInt64] $script:totalbytes = 0

# Returns a [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] object if it exists.
function Get-Directory {
  param( $item )

 if ( $ParamSetName -eq "Path" ) {
   if ( Test-Path -Path $item -PathType Container ) {
     $item = Get-Item -Path $item -Force
   }
 }
 elseif ( $ParamSetName -eq "LiteralPath" ) {
   if ( Test-Path -LiteralPath $item -PathType Container ) {
     $item = Get-Item -LiteralPath $item -Force
   }
 }
  if ( $item -and ($item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) ) {
   return $item
  }
```

}

```
 # Filter that outputs the custom object with formatted numbers.
 function Format-Output {
   process {
     $_ | Select-Object Path,
       @{Name="Files"; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f $_.Files}},
       @{Name="Size"; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f $_.Size}}
      }
   }

# Outputs directory statistics for the specified directory. With -recurse,
# the function includes files in all subdirectories of the specified
# directory. With -format, numbers in the output objects are formatted with
# the Format-Output filter.
function Get-DirectoryStats {
  param( $directory, $recurse, $format )

  Write-Progress -Activity "Get-DirStats.ps1" -Status "Reading 
 '$($directory.FullName)'"
  $files = $directory | Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse:$recurse | Where-
   Object  
  { -not $_.PSIsContainer }
   if ( $files ) {
    Write-Progress -Activity "Get-DirStats.ps1" -Status "Calculating 
   '$($directory.FullName)'"
    $output = $files | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length | Select-Object 
     `
     @{Name="Path"; Expression={$directory.FullName}},
     @{Name="Files"; Expression={$_.Count; $script:totalcount += $_.Count}},
     @{Name="Size"; Expression={$_.Sum; $script:totalbytes += $_.Sum}}
    }
     else {
        $output = "" | Select-Object `
        @{Name="Path"; Expression={$directory.FullName}},
        @{Name="Files"; Expression={0}},
        @{Name="Size"; Expression={0}}
       }
     if ( -not $format ) { $output } else { $output | Format-Output }
    }
  }

... the rest of the code did not seem relevant
```

Comment: What do you mean "variable that I need to change in order to specify a different path"? You don't change anything. You run the script and pass the path as a parameter: `.\Get-DirStats.ps1 -Path "C:\some\folder"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either specify the `$Path` variable when calling the script, or add a line that overrides the default value. I've highlighted where this is below.

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Path")]
 param( 

 [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Path",ValueFromPipeline =$true)]  

  $Path=(get-location).Path, ################ PATH IS SET HERE ##############
  [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="LiteralPath")]
  [String[]] $LiteralPath,
  [Switch] $Only,
```

When calling script:

```
C:>.\myscript.ps1 -Path "c:\temp"
```

Answer (score 0):

what you call the value depends on where you call it from.
the "main" part of this cmdlet accepts one of a couple parameters; path and literalPath, path would be used in preference to literal path. If neither is specified the current working directory will be the starting point. passing different arguments to the cmdlet seems to be the easiest technique. The author's intended usage.

BUT...
Up in that first function, after the parameters are bound in the "begin" section... the actual path is "$item".

inside Get-DirectoryStats it's being referred to as $directory.

There are places where it's referred to as $_.

There are a lot of articles on the topic of "scope". here's one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes